# Duplicity include with wildcards

Tags: backup, wildcard, duplicity

I want to backup all homes of my lxc containers with duplicity and i use (commandline simplified to the problem):

```
duplicity --include '/data/lxc/**/rootfs/home' --exclude '/data/lxc'
```

which does not match the homes, while

```
duplicity --include '/data/lxc/oneofthecontainers/rootfs/home' --exclude '/data/lxc'
```

works.

further testing shows, that

```
duplicity --include '/data/lxc/oneofthecontainers/rootfs/home/**' --exclude '/data/lxc'
```

does not work either. The manpage of duplicity tells me first match wins and `*` and `**` are allowed as wildcards, where `**` matches everything and `*` only one path component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know, why this does not work, but i solved it with `--include-globbing-filelist` and a filelist with `"+ "` and `"- "` entries for includes/excludes and now it works.